# Clear Apache Ignite Cache after WriteBehind

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ignite

I have a spring boot service that writes to an apache ignite cache.
The cache is writethrough,writebehind and readthrough.
I have mysql as a persistence store that the cache writesbehind to.
I would like to clear all cache entries that have been written to the mysql database from the cache.

I am using the cache as a staging area so that i do not make a db call every second instead i set the cache to writebehind every 30 seconds.

I would like to know how to clear to cache once writebehind is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You may call `cache.clear()` - it will not remove entries from underlying 3rd party persistence if that's what you ask.

Comment: I would like to clear the cache only once it has persisted to the db via writebehind. How do i know that it has written the record to clear the cache?

Comment: I think clearing the cache will not empty writeBehind queue, so it should be propagated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to extend CacheStore that you use, after writes to DB just create a task to remove persisted records, but make sure that you execute it in async way and with withSkipStore, otherwise you can easily get deadlock or/and thread starvation.